# Update column if submission time didnt exceed more than 15 minutes of deadline time

Tags: android-sqlite

What im after is to update the rows of table2 `remark` column. So if i have `10:00` as deadline time, the submission time must be between `10:00 - 10:15` so that it will be declared as `ONTIME`. Once it exceeds 15 minutes it will automatically update as `LATE`

Here are the tables below:

Table 1

```
    id | deadline_time
    ------------------------------
    1  | 10:00
```

Table 2

```
id | remark | time_submitted
----------------------------
1  | ONTIME | 10:14
2  | LATE   | 10:20
```

Here is what i've tried so far: its just the idea of how i can compare the time.

```
    public void checkTime(){
     String a = "10:00";
     String b= "10:15";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date x = null;
    Date y = null;

       try{
       x = format.parse(a);
       y = format.parse(b); 

       long diff = y.getTime() - x.getTime();
       long min = diff / (60* 1000) % 60;
       long hours = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 1000) % 60;

       Log.d("Difference: ", "Hours: "+hours + "Minutes: "+min);

       } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Im having trouble on creating sqlite statement for this one. Some ideas please to construct sqlite for this please! Also how can i compare the `time_submitted` if has a lot of data with just a single data from `deadline_time` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was get the difference between String a and String b. Then checked if the difference is greater than 15 then i will update the remark to LATE and ONTIME if not.

```
  public void checkTime(){
         Database hander = new Datababase(this);
         SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();

         String a = "10:00"; 
         String b= "10:30";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date x = null;
        Date y = null;

           try{
           x = format.parse(a);
           y = format.parse(b); 

           long diff = y.getTime() - x.getTime();
           long min = diff / (60* 1000) % 60;
           long hours = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 1000) % 60;

             if(min > 15) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET remark = 'LATE' WHERE id="2"); 
              } else 
               db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET remark = 'ONTIME' WHERE id="2"); 

           } catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```